# Remove default Date in LaTeX article

Tags: latex

How do I remove the default date that a documentclass{article} adds in LaTeX?
Thanks

Comment: More detailed answers on tex.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/omitting-the-date-when-using-maketitle

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try using `\date{}`.

Comment: To make this work (in case anyone is having trouble) I had to include this in the preamble before \begin{document}, not near \maketitle itself.

Comment: This just makes the date blank. It doesn't remove the vertical space where the date is supposed to be.

Comment: These are all _workarounds_, not _solutions_. 
The answer should mention that, and open the problem to add this as an _option_ to the `article` class.

Answer (score 21):

use `\date{}` before `"\begin{document}"`

Answer (score 5):

The command

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \title{text}
    \author{names}
    \maketitle
    \date{}
\end{document}
```

will give the out put as shown here:
[image: With date]

But the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \title{text}
    \author{names}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

will give the desired output, I believe, you want:
[image: Without date]

The command `\date{}` should be put after `\author{names}` and before `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 3):

Also ensure that you dont have any variation of this in your code.
`{\large \today}`

Answer (score 3):

A blank `\date{}` will still use some vertical spacing. Check [this post on TeX Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2760/14964) for a comprehensive list of alternatives, like the `titling` package.

Answer (score -1):

The exact code snippet to "copy and paste" is as follows:

```
\date{}
\begin{document}
```